# Can't find good Date Format : impossible parsing

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-format, informatica

I'm trying to **convert** the following String to a datetime format:

```
Sat Jan 14 13:55:34 CET 2017
```

If we consider that my date is in the `in_OutPut3` variable, I'm trying to use the following **format pattern** :

```
TO_DATE(in_OutPut3,'DY MON DD HH:MI:SS Z YYYY')
```

I receive the following **error** :

> The system failed to parse the date format : 'DY MON DD HH:MI:SS Z
>   YYYY'.

Do you have any idea what is this date format ?

Comment: Your error say the format is DY MON **MM** HH:MI:SS Z YYYY yet you claim your code says DY MON **DD** HH:MI:SS Z YYYY. Either one of these isn't literally the code you're working with or you've misidentified the error location. (Not to mention that a format that specifies both `MON` and `MM` would be deeply weird)

Comment: You are right, I changed the code but not the error. My mistake I correct the post.

Comment: Are you referring to an Oracle function to convert dates or an Informatica function ?

Comment: It is an Informatica function but it's name is TO_DATE()

Answer (score 1):

You have a timezone embedded in your string so try using the TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ function. TO_DATE is not designed to work with timezones.

The following works on 11g;

```
select to_timestamp_tz('Sat Jan 14 13:55:34 CET 2017','DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY') from dual
```

Comment: I had that as an answer too but deleted it; the question seems to be about Informatica and it's own `to_date`  function, rather than Oracle's RDBMS  `to_date` function. The `Z` format for time zone seems to work in Informatica.

Comment: You may be right . . . my Informatica knowledge is almost 10 years out of date !

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
to_timestamp('Sat Jan 14 13:55:34 CET 2017','Dy Mon dd hh:mi:ss ZZ yyyy');
```

Marco

Comment: Could be something to do differences in NLS set up but the above does not work for me on 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore the timezone while converting to Informatica Date type. Anyway, Informatica won't retain timezone information after converting to Data datatype. Put some symbols like underscore(_) to match 'CET'

```
TO_DATE(in_OutPut3, 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS ___ YYYY')
```

Also, looks like you have the hours in military format. In that case you have to use HH24.